# Reset DHCP lease time through CLI

Tags: shell, powershell, networking, command-line, windows-10

Probably because of the many changes I made over the last few years my Windows system drops local network connections after 30 minutes. Other systems in the same network don't have this problem so I assume it's not the router.

I found a few commands like

```
Set-DhcpServerv4Scope -ScopeId 192.168.0.1 –LeaseDuration (New-TimeSpan -Hours 12)
```

or

```
 netsh dhcp server scope 192.168.0.1 set optionvalue 000
```

Neither PowerShell nor the Command Prompt are recognizing them as valid commands.

How to set the DHCP settings to default through PowerShell, CMD or Registry?

Answer (score 1):

> [Neither] PowerShell nor the Command Prompt are recognizing them as valid commands.

You'll need to enable the DHCP tools, either from `appwiz.cpl` (Programs/Features) or with:

```
 Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName RSATClient-Roles-DHCP -Online
```

This will enable both the DHCP administration MMC snap-ins, the DHCP server powershell module and the `netsh dhcp` context.

---

Assuming you're on a client OS, you'll need to download and install the appropriate version of [Remote Server Administration Tools](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems) first

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm using my own Windows Home. Do I really have to install RSAT?

Comment: Yes, you do, and no, it won't work on Home edition. An alternative is to remote into the DHCP server and use the module on there

Comment: So it won't even work with RSAT installed on Home edition?